# Error while compiling the angular project

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, stomp, stompjs

```
[ERROR in ./node_modules/stompjs/lib/stomp-node.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\ANGULAR\websocket-example\node_modules\stompjs\lib'][1]
```

added stompjs to angular by
`npm install stompjs --save`

imported into component.ts
`import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';`

and got error when using like this
`let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/greeting");
     let ws = Stomp.over(socket);`

Comment: Have you added stompjs in the angular.json scripts block?

Comment: no i didn't. should i add in angular.json? I don't know, how to add.

Comment: Added the answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

To add an external library to your angular project, you can add those to the `angular.json`

```
"scripts":[
   "node_modules/stompjs/lib/stomp-node.js"
]
```